# MS SQL SERVER 2005 temp db log file size is increasing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Sometimes, when there is no load on the server, the size of the MS SQL database tempdb log file (templog.ldf) starts increasing. As a result, the available space on the C drive decreases. To resolve this issue, we need to restart the MS SQL server, after which the problem will be resolved. However, the same issue may repeat after some time when there is no load on the server.

Please suggest why the log file size starts increasing and how to fix this issue.

Comment: You can usually see in select * from sys.databases what prevents log from shrinking. a better alternative is to set max log size. If it's still increasing, it means there's something generating the log data, perhaps there's some sort of "load" after all

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271860/tempdb-log-file-growth-questions and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space. You should really consider upgrading: SQL2005 went out of support 7 years ago in 2016